# Creating a watchfolder and exporting to txt

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that lists all the files in a directory in real time. If a file is deleted than it deletes the filename in the txt file. If one file is added than it is added to the txt file.

So far I only got to create a program that lists and exports the content once. And as I am using a while(1) loop, it doesn`t stop creating files. I also need it to ignore duplicated names.

Can you help me with it? My code is as it follows:

```
import os
Path = 'Mypath'
arr = os.listdir(Path)
print (arr)

file1 = open ("File.txt","a")

while (1):
    for file in arr:
     #   if file not in file1:
            file1.writelines(file + "\n")
```

Comment: use contex manager for better handling of openning and closing files "with open(filename) as file1"

Comment: What OS? Some have the ability to alert you when a file has been created/deleted instead of you constantly checking.

Comment: try using .write() insted of .writelines(). it does not stop becuse of while loop, you can get rid of it

Comment: So you want an up to date file listing in a file. That's all?

Comment: @Wups Yes! But it needs to detect both added files and removed files when it is running.

Comment: Well you never change `arr` so you are constantly reading the same files list, regardless of the real folder's state...

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using polling.
If something changed, replace the whole file.

```
import os
import time

path = 'mypath/'
cur_list = None

while True:
    new_list = os.listdir(path)

    if new_list != cur_list:
        cur_list = new_list
        
        with open("File.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(cur_list))

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo `writelines` doesn't add line separators, which makes it quite useless in my opinion. Yes, the `if` is not necessary, but I don't want to write to the poor hard disk every few seconds, if there aren't any real changes maybe for hours.

Comment: Wow I was sure `writelines` adds those, otherwise what's the point... In that case, sorry ! ^_^